# Get timestamp for page ressources in a Hugo page bundle

Tags: hugo

I'm building a small image gallery for my website, and would like it to be ordered by creation date. The gallery is build as a page bundle with the individual images stored in a subfolder. Is there any way to access the creation date of the files from within a template, like you would use `.Date` or `.Lastmod` for posts?

I'm looking for solutions that doesn't require encoding the date in the file name or setting parameters for each image in the front-matter.

```html
<!--                              need something here 
                                           |                     -->
{{ range sort (.Resources.ByType "image") [?] "desc"}}
  {{ $image := .Fill "500x500 center" }}
  {{ $imageName := replace (path.Base .Name) (path.Ext .Name) ""}}
  <li>
    <figure>
      <a href="{{.RelPermalink}}">
        <img src="{{$image.RelPermalink}}" alt="{{$imageName}}" width="{{$image.Width}}px" height="{{$image.Height}}px"/>
      </a>
      <figcaption>{{$imageName}}</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
{{ end }}
```